# How to add a transparent border?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a simple user profile image, and a green state indicator.

I want to add a transparent border to the indicator, which surpasses the image in the background, like the image below.

[image: Expecting result]

It's easy when the background is a single color, I just have to add a border with the same color, but what to do when the background is a gradient or an image for example? If I add a white border, it looks like the image in the middle, and I would like to have a render like the right image.

How to achieve that ?

```css
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
}
.user-state {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #57d642;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/up/255/200/5" alt="">
    <div class="user-state"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Essentially, **you can't**. You'll probably need a clip-path to clip the image to that specific shape.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider SVG and [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) like below:

```css
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.user:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #57d642;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, pink, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="hole">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <!-- This circle is your hole on the top -->
      <circle r="28" cx="162" cy="38" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
    <!-- the clipath will replace border-radius -->
    <clipPath id="circle">
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="white" />            
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
<image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/200/200" mask="url(#hole)" clip-path="url(#circle)"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve that with pure css?

Answer (score -4):

Border: ?px
Border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Why? Rgba is for having a border, but you make it transparant

Comment: But that won't make the background of the object *behind* it transparent! See the required output in the images.

Comment: I think it should. If there is a border, and you make that border transparant, you'll get exactly what's needed. A visible border but transparant so the gradient background is showed as in the 3d picture

Comment: Try it...it won't cut into the image. Again, see the image of the required result.

Comment: Put it on .user-state and it will

Comment: @Daan_1978 instead of arguing show us how it works and we will get convinced :)

Comment: I was thinking.. and again and you are definitely right ^^ Sorry for my misunderstanding. It does work only on background side on my way. Didnt rly look further.